# Distance to object python

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pytorch, distance

I have an image of a car and a corresponding bounding box. For example:

```
(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
(504.8863220214844, 410.2454833984375, 
937.6451416015625, 723.9139404296875)
```

[image]

That's how I draw boxes:

```py
def plot_results(pil_img, prob, boxes):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
    plt.imshow(pil_img)
    ax = plt.gca()
    for p, (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), c in zip(prob, boxes.tolist(), COLORS * 100):
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((xmin, ymin), xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin,
                                   fill=False, color=c, linewidth=3))
        cl = p.argmax()
        text = f'{CLASSES[cl]}: {p[cl]:0.2f}'
        ax.text(xmin, ymin, text, fontsize=15,
                bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

I want to measure the distance from car to camera. If the car is nearby, the distance value should be around 0.2-0.4 If the car is far from the camera, the distance value should be around 0.6-0.8.

I also found a solution for my problem: https://pythonprogramming.net/detecting-distances-self-driving-car/
But here author uses an old model. This model doesn't work well.

Comment: It's not about the model, once you have the bbox data for the car class, it's all about geometry. For example you can use the `area_of_the_bbox/area_of_image` over a linear or non linear relation to the distance. Also use the position of the box, the more is close to the center, the higher the probability of collision.

Comment: @iGian, if it's all about geometry, tell me how to solve my problem. I don't know geometry)

Comment: What's the real world height of the object? What's the focal length of the camera? Estimating distance from a single image is ambiguous, since a big object far away can look identical to a small object close to the camera.

Comment: I'm sorry that its not possible or your problem statement is too vague, until or unless you have additional information or a dataset to train on this problem setting. In the process of image acquisition 3D points of the scene is transformed into 2D through a series of transformations. Given an image and a bbox, its almost impossible to tell how further it is from the camera without a trained network on this kind of problem.

Comment: @alex-uarent-alex do you just want your code to work exactly like the link you provided? They aren't measuring distance, they are just measuring `bounding box width / image width` ratio, and just arbitrarily defining a "too close" range.  Measuring based on width of bounding box is flawed for many reasons. One issue is that two vehicles at the same distance can have two different values if one is driving left to right of the camera, and other towards or away from the camera.

Comment: @DSander, do you just want your code to work exactly like the link you provided?
-Yes

Comment: @alex-uarent-alex what value do you expect to see on the car in your example? 0.5?

Comment: @DSander, yes. Something like that. I expect to see  0.4< x < 0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you requested code that works similarly to the link you provided. I want to make it clear your source example isn't measuring distance. It is only measuring the width of the bounding boxes on the vehicles. The logic is based on the concept that larger widths are closer to the camera, and a smaller widths are further from the camera. This approach has many flaws due to optical illusions and lack of size and scale context. At any rate:

```
def plot_results(pil_img, prob, boxes):
    granularity = 3 # fiddle with this to scale
    img_width_inches = 16
    img_height_inches = 10 
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(img_width_inches, img_height_inches))       
    img_width_pixels = img_width_inches * fig.dpi
    img_height_pixels = img_height_inches * fig.dpi     
    plt.imshow(pil_img)
    ax = plt.gca()
    for p, (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), c in zip(prob, boxes.tolist(), COLORS * 100):   
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((xmin, ymin), xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin,
                               fill=False, color=c, linewidth=3))
        cl = p.argmax()
        text = f'{CLASSES[cl]}: {p[cl]:0.2f}'
        ax.text(xmin, ymin, text, fontsize=15, bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5))
        # get width of bounding box
        box_width_pixels = xmax - xmin
        # normalize the box width with image width
        normalized_width = box_width_pixels / img_width_pixels
        # invert with 1 - apply power of granularity and round to 1 place
        apx_distance = round(((1 - (normalized_width))**granularity), 1) 
        # get middle of box in pixels     
        mid_x = (xmin + xmax) / 2
        mid_y = (ymin + ymax) / 2
        # draw value
        ax.text(mid_x, mid_y, apx_distance, fontsize=15, color="white")
        # normalize the middle x position with image width  
        mid_x_normalized = mid_x / img_width_pixels
        # create arbitrary ranges and logic to consider actionable
        if apx_distance <= 0.5:
            if mid_x_normalized > 0.3 and mid_x_normalized < 0.7:
                ax.text(50, 50, "WARNING!!!", fontsize=26, color="red")
    
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The main difference between this code and the example you provided is that the bounding box values you've given `(504.8863220214844, 410.2454833984375, 937.6451416015625, 723.9139404296875)` represent pixels. However, the code in the example has bounding box values that are already normalized between 0 and 1 in relation to the image size. This is why I verbosely defined the image width and height in inches and pixels (also for self explaining code). They are needed to normalize the pixel based widths and positions so they are between 0 and 1 to match the logic in your example, and which you requested. These values can also be helpful when trying to actually measure sizes and distances.

If you are interested in taking this further. I recommend reading about the laws of perspective. Here is an interesting place to start: https://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/perspect2.html#distance